# Is there any specific destination in Southeast Asia famed for dentistry?

Tags: health, southeast-asia, destinations, countries, medical-tourism

I've heard in the past that certain countries or cities are popular "medical tourism" destinations, but not paid a whole lot of attention.

But this morning just three days before my next overlanding adventure I've had a front tooth break.

I'm not postponing my trip to go to the dentist in Australia. Rather I'm interested to know if there is some place people travel to in Southeast Asia specifically due to there being low cost but well regarded dental care?

If there's not an actual medical/dental tourism location specifically, then I'd still like to know which country would have a good balance of budget and respected work.

I'm starting in Kuala Lumpur and expect to be travelling for nine months or so with few specific plans. Some friends think they've heard of people going to Thailand for dental work but don't have specific info.

Comment: I just spent several months travelling Southeast Asia, where I heard Cambodia apparently has outstanding dentistry clinics. I believe a particular clinic in Phnom Penh is very popular amongst expats, but I can't recall the name at the moment. Didn't go myself though... Last I heard about Thailand was more in the context of transgender surgeries, but I'm sure you'd be able to find reputable low-cost, high-standard dentists there too.

Comment: Small addendum: [this website](http://www.patientsbeyondborders.com/procedure/dentistry) might be of interest (and seems to confirm the Thailand statement).

Answer (score 4):

You likely will be able to find good dental clinics in Kuala Lumpur, but I have no firsthand experience.

Thailand does have good dental services, reasonable pricing and properly trained dentists and dental surgeons.  Quite a large number of folks come to Thailand specifically for dental work such as implants, crowns, etc.  But also for general cleanings and check ups as costs are quite low.  Plus a fair number of the dentists at the better clinics received their training and certification abroad in places like the USA, Australia, etc.

If you peruse the Bangkok and Chiang Mai forums on TripAdvisor you will find quite a few threads with dental clinic info and recommendations.  You will also find a number of threads on the ThaiVisa forum as well.

Comment: Can confirm. Medical tourism in Thailand is a big business. I have seen Travel agent offices in Hospitals in BKK. Here is a BBC Article about this topic: http://www.bbc.com/travel/feature/20120828-the-rise-of-medical-tourism-in-bangkok

Answer (score 2):

If you still haven't been yet, and you'll be passing through Bangkok I have had positive experiences working with Bangkok International Dental Center (professionally). They have lots of international accreditations (JCI, ISO) and also work with Straumann (really good Swiss dental implants) which is another testament to their high standards.

[Prices are very reasonable](https://www.medigo.com/en/clinic/Thailand/Bangkok/bangkok-international-dental-center-53bd12e8c01df) and they pride themselves on being very open and upfront about prices so no surprises :)

Good luck and hope you get it sorted!

Florence

Answer (score 2):

Thailand. I've lived n BKK for a couple of years and never had any problems with Thantakit International. Had a couple of root canal treatments, fillings and cleanings. The place mainly provides dental treatments to expats and most of the dentists were trained in the US so I never had an issue in terms of communication and services. Of course, you should be very cautious in picking a health and dental facility. Even some of my friends go on a dental holiday in Thailand. Two of them stayed there for good. :)